# What is the difference between ptr = my_array and ptr = &my_array[0][0] in C language?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, reference, dereference

I am a newbie to C. For the following code:

```
int *ptr;
int my_array[5][5] = {{1,2},{3,4,5},{6},{7}};
```

I noticed my compiler produced a warning for:

```
ptr = my_array;
```

But worked fine for:

```
ptr = &my_array[0][0];
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An array used in expressions with rare exceptions is converted to the pointer to its first element.

If you have an array like this

```
int my_array[5][5];
```

then it is an array of arrays that is the elements of the array have types `int[5]`. For example the expression `my_array[0]` has the type `int[5]`. So the array used in expressions is converted to a pointer of type `int ( * )[5]` that points to its first element (to its first "row").

Types `int *` and `int ( * )[5]` are different types and there is no an implicit conversion from one type to another.

The expression `&my_array[0][0]` has the type `int *`.

So if you want to reinterpret the array as a one-dimensional array you need to use the implicit cast

```
ptr = ( int * )my_array;
```

Investigate this demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int my_array[5][5] = 
    { 
        { 1, 2 },
        { 3, 4, 5 },
        { 6 },
        { 7 } 
    };

    for (int(*p)[5] = my_array; p != my_array + 5; ++p)
    {
        for (int *q = *p; q != *p + 5; ++q)
        {
            printf("%d ", *q);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Its output is

```
1 2 0 0 0
3 4 5 0 0
6 0 0 0 0
7 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```